# Synchronizing two Branches in SVN without reintegration

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I have Feature Branch of my trunk. At first, I was rebasing my Feature Branch with the trunk by simply merging the changes down to the branch. I did the reintegration by a merge --reintegrate. The branch then was dead and everything fine.

Now, I have a different requirement. The branch shall not die and it should also periodically be integrated back into the trunk.

So, what I do is, I merge from the Feature Branch into trunk and then record merge only this revision back to the Feature Branch to prevent it from beeing merged another time when I rebase.

My question is now how to do the Rebase? Is it same way? Which means I have to merge the changes from the trunk into Feature Branch and the record the merge only back to trunk? Or is it even unneccesary to do a record merge?

Yes, I know this isn't really the way, Subversion is designed for but currently I need to it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by rebasing in the - there is no such thing built into svn that compares to eg the git rebase procedure.

However, if you use a fairly recent version of svn (1.8+ is definitely sufficient, with 1.7+ you would have to check), branches never have to die, and you also do not have to make record-only merges (the `--reintegrate` flag is also obsolete). Just do a normal `merge` from trunk to branch and vice versa if you want to synchronize between the two. Svn will take care of the rest for you under the hood. You can also keep your branch alive and continue to merge changes in both directions indefinitely.

Comment: With rebasing I just meant a merge from trunk. Sorry for that unclear term. I'm using svn 1.6. So I cant use the automatic merge and I also don't want  to merge the whole branches into each other. I need to merge special revision ranges (some people call it cherry picking). What I observed is that if you have merged a specific revision from your branch to your trunk and then try to merge a revision range that includes this merge commit from your trunk back into your branch, subversion is trying to merge it again. What I guess can only be avoided by a record merge.

Comment: Uh. Yes, I guess in this case you need a combination of record-only merges and specifying certain revision ranges. You really should consider updating to a more current svn version. It is only necessary to use a newer *client* and it prevents a ton of headaches like the one mentioned by you.

Comment: Thanks! I had a chance to test SVN at version 1.8. But it was not possible to do an automatic merge and to specify a range of revisions at the same time. When I use a range revision merge it seems that I always run into the trouble of record only merges.